# 'Still' meaning 'also'

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering whether or not the word 'still' could ever have the meaning of 'as well' or 'also'. Translating a sentence into English, I came up with: 'My life has been a lie and my death a lie still.' For some reason it feels good to me, but I need to know if it's grammatically correct, or if it makes any sense at all. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: The title refers to *since*, is that just a typo?

Comment: I'm so sorry! I meant to write 'still'.

Comment: Note that _still_ **means** 'dead' (it's an opposite of 'quick'). That adds a resonance to _.. and my death a lie still' which makes it, as you say, feel good.

Comment: "Still" has acquired a meaning of "as well"/"also", since it's often used where the literal sense is "continuing", and that term (or variations) may be used as a conjunction of sorts to extend a series of statements.  Of course, "...death a lie still" is an unintended(?) pun, since in death you do lie still (not moving).

Comment: The archaic meaning of *still* as *always* or *forever* is also apposite, compounding the pun.

Answer (score 1):

"Still" has adverbial meanings, but "also" is not one of them. I'll let you read [the definitions](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/still?s=t) rather than repeating them all, but "as previously" is probably closest to what you were looking for. For example:

> "I've been running a mile every day for the last ten years, and I still am."

While you could interpret the sentence you quote ("My life has been a lie and my death a lie still.") as meaning that I am not really dead, I would take it in a more poetic sense: "I've been lying to people all my life and even in death I am lying to them".

For example, this might be a man who was thought to be a war hero, but in reality was only on the battlefield in order to pick the pockets of dead men. He is killed in what looks like a heroic assault on an enemy position, but the reality is he was just trying to get to where the richest pickings were. he presents a false image in death, just as he did previously ("still") in life.

Answer (score 0):

Still may properly be used, as you are using it, as an adverb. Yes.

However ...your sentence I would like better translated like this:

'My life is a lie and my death a lie still.'

...still *being* alive 'has been a lie' would be improper.

Comment: I understand _my life has been a lie_ as "everything about my life has been a lie", not "it is a lie that I ever lived".

Comment: Yes. I'm going for clarity. Actually, the way you wrote the explanation is really quite a good sentence:

I understand my life has been a lie as "everything about my life has been a lie" ...

Comment: The whole sentence is: 'I, too, must learn how one dies, in order to prevent being said that my life has been a lie and my death a lie still.' I hope this clarifies what I meant by 'has been a lie'.

Comment: Yes. I understood, and _understand_ faster, better, clearer **now** with the whole sentence.

That's the thing about grammar: it's there to bring crisp clarity.

Fun!